# EF Insert with relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm creating an MVC 5 website to track results of golf tournaments. I have 3 key tables, *Event* has many *Results*. *Golfer* has many *Results*. So for any row in the *Result* table I can link to the golfer and event.

I am using EF6 code first to persist to SQL Server.

Here's my poco for Event:

```
public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string VenueName { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public String FirstTeeOff { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Fee { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

And for Golfer:

```
public class Golfer
    {
        public int GolferId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int CurrentHandicap { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

And for Result:

```
public class Result
    {
        public int ResultId { get; set; }
        public Golfer Golfer { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public bool Attendance { get; set; }
        public int HandicapPlayed { get; set; }
        public int ScoreCarded { get; set; }

        public Result()
        {
            Event = new Event();
            Golfer = new Golfer();
        }
    }
```

Here's my model context:

```
public class ModelContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, SANDGolf.DataLayer.IModelContext
    {
        public ModelContext() : base("ModelContextConString") { }

        public virtual DbSet<SANDGolf.DomainClasses.Golfer> Golfers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SANDGolf.DomainClasses.Event> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SANDGolf.DomainClasses.Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following controller action to try to insert into the result table to record attendance.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ExpectedAttendance(ExpectedAttendanceViewModel eaVM)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(GolferAttendanceViewModel gaVM in eaVM.GolferAttendanceViewModel)
                {
                    DomainClasses.Result resultDomain = new DomainClasses.Result();

                    resultDomain.Attendance = gaVM.Attending;
                    resultDomain.Event.EventId = eaVM.Event.EventId;
                    resultDomain.Golfer.GolferId = gaVM.Golfer.GolferId;

                    _context.Entry(resultDomain).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

When the line _context.SaveChanges(); executes I get the following error:

*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).       Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*

I am new to EF so would be grateful if anyone could let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not just calling _context.Results.Add(resultDomain) and then saving the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to switch to foreign key associations. For example:

```
public virtual Golfer Golfer {get;set;}
```

will become:

```
public int GolferId {get;set;}
public virtual Golfer Golfer {get;set;}
```

Using this approach you can just set for example:

```
Golfer myGolfer = getGolferById(1); // or gaVM.Golfer.GolverId;
Result.GolferId = myGolfer.GolferId;
```

You can read more about this on [my blog](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2014/01/16/relationships-in-entity-framework-code-first/).

And when adding a new entity to the database you should not use:

```
_context.Entry(resultDomain).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

but use @danludwig's solution.

Comment: I re-visited this project today to make further changes. I found Marthijn's advice very helpful. This is backed up by chapter 4 of the O'Reilly Programming Entity Framework Code First, which states - "IT’S JUST EASIER WITH FOREIGN KEY PROPERTIES"

Answer (score 1):

Navigation properties also need to be virtual.

```
public virtual Golfer Golfer { get; set; }
public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
```

Also, like Scott Corbett said, your new entity should not have modified state, but rather added state:

```
_context.Entry(resultDomain).State = EntityState.Added;
```

... or better yet:

```
_context.Results.Add(resultDomain);
```

Comment: What if I want to update a result record, should I still use the Add method? Sorry I won't have chance to try this until tonight

Comment: No. You use Add for inserts. If you want to update, you would change the state to Modified as in your question.

Comment: It worked! Thanks danludwig and Scott. I guess I'm having trouble letting EF do the work for me. I'm so used to inserting the child, getting the foreign key then inserting the parent

Comment: Yes, EF will to the fk/pk stuff for you.